# Removing script and styles version query string with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How do i change this:
    example.com/css/style.css?ver=3.5.3
    examle.com/css/settings.css?ver=4.6.9

in to this:
    example.com/css/style.css
    example.com/css/settings.css

I have this code on my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This code however is not functioning. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to do this in htaccess vs the html?

Comment: Do you just need to rewrite them off (for cosmetic purposes) or actually remove the version numbering from the assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your .htaccess in the document root if you want to do it this way. Let me know how it works for you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ver=(.+)
RewriteRule ^css/(style|settings)(\.css)$ /css/$1$2? [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your sugestion, however it also did not solve the issue.

Comment: I'm running a Wordpress site and want to remove all version strings from script and styles. I managed to acomplish this on 99% of files without breaking any installed plugins and themes. However there is a very  stubborn plugin (Revolution Slider) that just keeps the ?ver=xxxx no matter what. I modified your code and was successful in removing the the version number of the plugin.

Comment: Here is the modified code. Maybe it can be useful to other experiencing this issue with revolution slider.                                                                  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rev=(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ $1$3? [L]
</IfModule>